# How to scale a loaded SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, swfloader

I want to load a swf into a Flex application and scale it down into a thumbnail-size.

I've looked at [dimensions of loaded swf's stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245420/dimensions-of-loaded-swfs-stage), but it does not really address my need: I want to size it and keep all the pieces inside a container.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to scale the container that the SWF is in. For example, in vanilla AS3 you'd load into a Loader object. You'd just have to set the scaleX and scaleY properties of that object to scale it down.

Comment: How do I figure out how large the SWF is, accounting for it dynamically moving elements ?

Comment: You don't really... all you can do is scale it and mask it (if it's rectangular mask, check out using scrollRect - it's much faster than an actual mask)